# Hbase for File I/O. and way to connect HDFS on remote client

Tags: nosql, hadoop, hbase, hdfs

Please be aware that I’m not fluent in English before you read. 
I'm new at NoSQL,and now trying to use HBase for File storage. - I'll store Files in HBase as binary.
I don't need any statistics. Only what I need is File storage.
IS IT RECOMMENDED!?!?

I am worrying about I/O speed.

Actually, because I couldn't find any way to connect HDFS with out hadoop, I wanna try HBase for file storage. I can’t set up Hadoop on client computer. I was trying to find some libraries - like JDBC for RDBMS - which help the client connect HDFS to get files. but I couldn’t find anything and just have chosen HBase instead of connection library.

Can I get any help from someone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on your file sizes. In Hbase it is generally not recommended to store files or LOBs, the default max keyvalue size is 10mb. I have raised that limit and run tests with >100mb values but you do risk OOME your regionservers as it has to hold the entire value in memory - config your JVMs memory with care.

When this type of question is asked on the hbase-users listserve the usual response is to recommend using HDFS if you files can be large.

You should be able to use Thrift to connect to HDFS to bypass installing the Hadoop client on your client computer.

Comment: Thank you so much~! Before I read your answer, I had read/write performance test between HDFS and HBase.
the result is this. File Size : 20k ~ 1m File count : 200 HDFS Write : 50079 Read : 44953 HBase Write : 16640 Read : 2766 am I miss something~?

Comment: @Byung I'm not sure I understand - are those files/sec performance numbers? Hbase generally shines for throughput when you have many clients. If you are using Java there is a [multi-threaded asynchronous client](https://github.com/danirayan/asynchbase) that you might want to look into.